# Adding currency and percentage signs without converting to string

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a TKTable script that is working fine. When I wanted to add more clarity to my data by adding some symbols I'm now unable to sort correctly that data.

Is there a way to have the data with the correct symbols but still can be read as int/float and be sorted by Tkinter?

This is the code I use to add the symbols to the data:

```
data[i] = {'CTR': "{}%".format(round(result['ctr'],2)), 'Spent': "{}$".format(result['spent']), 'CPM': "{}$".format(result['cpm']), 'CPC': "{}$".format(result['cpc'])}
```

This what it looks like when I try to sort ($) values:

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: Why not remove them, sort and add them after ?

Comment: Because, unfortunately, the sort function is not linked to the script that generates the data!

Comment: What do you mean by "sorted by Tkinter"?

Comment: I mean, as TkinterTable is a Tkinter library, is there a way to make Tkinter sort values that contain symbols? I know that I can influence the function "sort" in the library but I have little knowledge of Python so far to even localize the function in the code :( May be there is a hack or a workaround to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must separate the data from its display representation:

- Keep the data in a data structure (dict, tuple, class), where you can sort it, and do all other operations needed.
- When these operations are done, create another data structure that will hold the formatted data, ready to display.
- Then, display these formatted values.

If a change occurs, you go back to the data and modify it to reflect the change; you then re-create the formatted display data, and display it.